# Insert data from one table to another using linQ

Tags: linq, transfer

I have two tables `Cart(ItemID, Name, Price, Quantity, CartID, CustID)` and `PP( invoiceID, itemID, orderQuantity, PricePerUnit, includesID)`.

Now I have to insert values (`ItemID,  Price, Quantity`) from the `Cart` table into the `pp` table where `cart.custid = session[customerID]`. But the values not getting inserted into the `pp` table. Not sure if the `AsEnumerable` syntax used here is correct.

```
DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();

var Carts = context.Carts;
pp newpp = new pp();

var p = Carts.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new pp()
{
    itemID = x.ItemID,
    PricePerUnit = Convert.ToDouble(x.Price),
    orderQuantity = x.Quantity,
    invoiceID = invoiceNum

});

context.pps.InsertAllOnSubmit(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be calling the `SubmitChanges` method on the `context`. This is required to actually persist the data back to the database. The `InserAllOnSubmit` method merely marks them as needing to be inserted. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.insertallonsubmit.aspx) for info

Comment: Ya , I didnot realize that it has to be submitted. Now it is working. Thankyou!!